How can create own ValueExis object
In Qt there is a ChartView object with its own ValueAxis, but I need to create it myself due to technical reasons. Could anyone tell me the best way to fill it with tickmarks? Based on the maximum and minimum, it consists of lines (major with values).
I probably need to do this through the repeater, but what exactly should I fill out, column or row?
Thx

I tried this option, but for some reason there is an empty space before the first tickmark and the last one. I don't know if this is a suitable option
ColumnLayout
{
anchors.right: mainLine.left
anchors.top: root.top
anchors.bottom: root.bottom
    Repeater
    {
        model: 8

        delegate: Rectangle
        {
            width: root.width / 2
            height: 2
            color: "#44ff0000"
        }
    }

}
